# SwiftCharts graph not in bounds

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, swiftcharts

So I have am using the SwiftCharts graph, and have it setup like this.

```
func roundToTens(_ x : Double) -> Int {
    return 10 * Int((x / 10.0).rounded(.awayFromZero))
}

func createChart(){
let chartConfig = BarsChartConfig(
    valsAxisConfig: ChartAxisConfig(from: 0, to: Double(roundToTens(maximum)), by: Double(roundToTens(maximum)/6))
)

let frame = view2.bounds


let chart = BarsChart(
    frame: frame,
    chartConfig: chartConfig,
    xTitle: "Categories",
    yTitle: "Y axis",
    bars: test,
    color: UIColor.red,
    barWidth: 20
)

self.chart = chart
view2.addSubview(chart.view)
self.view.addSubview(view2)
}
```

However, the graph ends up looking like this.

[image]

I tried fixing the bounds, by adding Margins to the bounds but all it did was make the graph look wrong. Is anyone familiar with the SwiftCharts framework and how I can centre the graph to the middle and make it overall smaller so that the top y-axis number is visible

Comment: What do you mean by made the graph look wrong?

Comment: It completely got rid of the top number and shifted the whole graph to the left.

Comment: Could the view containing the graph just be placed incorrectly? It looks like it starts in the same place as the navigation bar does.